# Print cascading table

Tags: php, algorithm, html-table, cascade

I'm trying to load data from database and display it in table like here:

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1857/cijene.jpg

In database I have two tables:

```
cities (id, name)
prices (id, city1_id, city2_id, price)
```

For example, the printed table for 4 cities would look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>city1</td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td> price_city1-city2</td>
  <td>city2</td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td> price_city1-city3</td>
  <td> price_city2-city3</td>
  <td>city3</td>
  <td> </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td> price_city1-city4</td>
  <td> price_city2-city4</td>
  <td> price_city3-city4</td>
  <td>city4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Does someone know what's the PHP statement to echo this kind of tables?

Comment: Have you retrieved the data into an array or object yet?

Comment: By the way, the link in your question requires authentication.  Please mirror the relevant parts somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for comment!
I've edited post, the image can be seen now.
I didn't retrieve data into an array, but that is not problem... I need help to write algorithm to print this diagonal table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This single query gets all required data
// NOTE: this query assumes that your price data is entered
//   such that from_city always alphabetically precedes to_city!
$sql =
    "SELECT a.name AS from_city, b.name AS to_city, price ".
    "FROM prices ".
    "INNER JOIN cities AS a ON a.id=prices.city1_id ".
    "INNER JOIN cities AS b ON b.id=prices.city2_id";


// connect and do query
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
$q = mysql_query($sql, $conn);


// Stuff all data into an array for manipulation;
//   keep list of all cities mentioned
$price = array();
$cities = array();
while (($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) !== false) {
    $from = $res['from_city'];
    $cities[ $from ] = true;

    $to = $res['to_city'];
    $cities[ $to ] = true;

    $price[$to][$from] = $res['price'];
}

// Invert to get alphabetical list of cities
$cities = array_keys($cities);
sort($cities);
$num = count($cities);


// some utility functions
function table($rows) {
    return '<table>'.join($rows).'</table>';
}
function row($cells) {
    return '<tr>'.join($cells).'</tr>';
}
function cell($text) {
    $text = (string) $text;
    if (strlen($text)==0)
        $text = '&nbsp;';
    return '<td>'.$text.'</td>';
}


// The data is now in the desired order;
// produce output as HTML table
$rows = array();
for ($to = 0; $to < $num; ++$to) {
    $t = $cities[$to];
    $cells = array();

    for ($from = 0; $from < $to; ++$from) {
        $f = $cities[$from];

        if isset($price[$t]) && isset($price[$t][$f])
            $text = $price[$t][$f];
        else
            $text = '';

        $cells[]= cell($text);
    }

    $cells[]= cell($t);    // add destination-label

    for ($from = $to+1; $from < $num; ++$from)   // pad to proper number of cells
        $cells[]= cell('');

    $rows[]= row($cells);
}
$html = table($rows);


// show results!
echo $html;
```

Comment: Hi Hugh,
thanks a lot for answering, this was very helpful!
Cheers,
Ilija

Answer (score 1):

I've used a very simple approach to converting the results of a query to an HTML table.
I test that $query_result is true and fetch the results as an associative array...

```
$query_result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if ($query_result) {

    while ($columns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {

        echo "<tr>\n";

        foreach ($columns as $name => $column) {
            echo "<td>";
            printf("%s",$columns[$name]);
            echo "</td>\n";
        }

        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
```

EDIT: Now I've been able to look at your table, I can see that I haven't really answered your question. The query is obviously very important. Does the question become 'how do I create a query which returns results which can be turned into a table by my simple-minded approach?'

I hope someone else has a few ideas.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I think that you didn't understand my question, or what would be more truthful is that I didn't asked it proper :)
Please check this image: http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1857/cijene.jpg 
Price from Beograd to Novi Sad is 100. Price from Beograd to Nis is 200 etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat at the edge of practicality, but I'm approaching this problem more as an exercise in "doing it right."

I would do a simple select of each table and insert in to an array:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM cities";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM prices";

$results1 = mysql_query( $query1 );
$results2 = mysql_query( $query2 );

while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $results1 ) ) $cities[] = $row['name'];
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $results2 ) ) $prices[] = array(
                                                               $row['city1_id'],
                                                               $row['city2_id'], 
                                                               $row['name']
                                                            );
```

I would then use this to dynamically create two javascript lists:

```
$java_array1 = "var Cities = new Array;\n";
foreach( $cities as $key=>$city ) $java_array1 .= "Cities[$key] = \"$city\";\n";
$java_array2 = "var Prices = new Array;\n";
foreach( $cities as $key=>$price ) $java_array2 .= "Prices[$key] = new Array(
                                                                     \"{$price[0]}\",
                                                                     \"{$price[1]}\",
                                                                     \"{$price[2]}\",
                                                                  );\n";
```

I would next output a table with carefully crafted ids for each cell. I would use code very similar to that in the first answer, but I would give each cell a unique id of `"cell-<row>-<col>"`.

The last thing I would do would be whip up some `onload` javascript which would populate the  table using the appropriate pairings. My javascript is quite rusty, but it would look something like this (NOTE: pseudocode follows):

```
n = 1;
for( var i in cities )
{
    // set city names on the diagonal
    document.getElementById( 'cell-'&i&'-'&i ).innerHTML = names[i];
    n = n + 1;
}

for( var j in prices )
{
    // use the city IDs in the prices array (see earlier code initializing
    // prices array) to place the prices
    document.getElementById( 'cell-'&prices[1]&'-'&prices[2] ).innerHTML = prices[0];
}
```

I almost certainly messed up some of that javascript; use at your own risk.

This is a lot more complex than the simpler answer given above, but this is the only way I can think of doing it so that it makes "sense." Basically, with this method, you place everything where it *should* be, and you don't have to worry about odd tables and weird selects.